# Can Pywinauto Track or Log Error with an Application?

Tags: python, pywinauto

Is there any way to track or log error in Pywinauto (eg a pop-up window does not appear, etc.) ?  I am trying to track if a window opens correctly or not. I am also trying to verify values in an Excel Worksheet.  Is this possible ?  Oh!  Yes, I am a newbie to Python and Pywinauto.  Thanks for your assistance !!

Comment: You can improve your question by showing what you have done to solve your problem yourself. There seem to be two questions here: Try to make one posting contain only one question.

Comment: You are correct.  I want to know if there is a way to log an error with PyWinAuto.  Let say I open an Excel sheet and I look at contents of Cell(1,3).  Cell(1,3) does not have the expected value.  Can PyWinAuto create a log stating that value is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

For working with MS Excel I would recommend using standard `win32com.client` module (it's included into ActivePython, or pyWin32 extensions can be installed by `pip install pypiwin32` for example). Almost every Microsoft application has nice `IDispatch` COM interface. By the way standard docs example shows MS Excel usage. ;)

For handling window opening pywinauto contains `.Wait('ready')` method for the window specification. So something like that should work or raise an exception in case of failure:

```
app.MainWindowTitle.Wait('ready') # 'ready' == 'exists visible enabled'
# or
app.Window_(title_re='^some regular expr - .*$', class_name='#32770').Wait('visible enabled')
```

You can do the same if the window is closing:

```
app.SomeDialog.WaitNot('exists', timeout=20) # default or implicit timeout is 5 sec.
```

If you need `bool` return value instead of raising an exception, then use methods `.Visible()`, `.Exists()`, `.Enabled()` and `.IsActive()`.